# Mathematical card tricks

Tags: recreational-mathematics

For quite some time I have taken interest in analyzing card tricks that make use of a deep knowledge of advanced mathematics and there's been some progress. However, all the tricks I've tried decoding seem to be based on elementary math which any serious high school number aficionado can understand and appreciate if not decipher. Is there a card trick that's so outlandishly brilliant that mathematicians need to wreck their heads over it? 
P.S: I'm after the holy grail of card tricks that require minimal sleight of hand

Comment: Are you sure you are on the correct site? This site is about the computer program Mathematica, a computer algebra system and more. Perhaps you need to ask on Mathematics stack exchange.

Comment: Richard Turner is probably the person you’re looking for...

Comment: Do you mean tricks whose operation involves higher maths, or would a trick do if it didn't, but higher maths is needed to prove that it works? Is the Kruskal count the sort of thing you're after?

Comment: @Hugh I see. I sure will post the question over there. Thanks

Comment: @morbo Thanks for the information

Comment: @RosieF Yes, I'm looking for tricks like those based on the Kruskal count, one the layman can appreciate but not see through.

Comment: Perhaps of interest: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9754/magic-trick-based-on-deep-mathematics